# Re-using views between ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, code-reuse, razorengine, razorgenerator

I have a customer facing ASP.NET MVC app and we are in the process of building a sister app. I want to be able to share some of the existing layouts, views from the main app. I looked at using RazorGenerator which seems to be good at extracting views into a separate binary, but in my case, I dont have the luxury of making changes to the main app. Razor Generator insists on creating the .cs files right next to the cshtml files. I am free to setup the new sister app as I want to.

Is there any other way I can achieve re-use of certain views from my main app? One way I could achieve this is by setting up the sister app's repo right next to the main app and use relative paths achieve the re-use, but that sounds ugly to me.

Any ideas?

Thanks
Kay

Comment: There would be a few options here. BUT, did i understand you correctly you cant change code on the other app? If yes, the you options just got very limited. Personally, I would be jumping at the chance to write a green field app with out using a legacy product and introducing loads of spaghetti code. But i am weird that way.

Comment: Yes, thats correct. I dont have the luxury of updating the current customer facing app. I was excited too at first, when I heard green field, but then I realized that we were mandated to use some of the existing layouts and views (there is no free lunch i guess). What are my options?

Comment: You are going to run into issue if you try to interact with code you have no control over. if they change a view and your app did not want it. You may hit security walls also with XXS. your safest option by far is to copy what you want from the old to the new.

Comment: You should be able to reference the business layer of the other app so you dont have to reinvent the whole thing

Comment: Why not do ajax calls to the old application with proper parameters and use the result (same views) directly into your html?

Comment: @KevDevMan Copying is one solution, but I fear we are going to end up having two different flavors of Views and when we need a change it requires changes in both applications

Comment: My point is what happens when there is a change only required in ONE app. If its for the other app, you have no control over that, so you have to hack your code to get it to work on your side. And if you need something in your app that the other app does not need THEN you have to copy everything anyway because you have no control over the other app. Cut the cord not to avoid heart ache in the future.

Comment: @KevDevMan What we are trying to re-use are some basic styles, css, javascripts and a few views. If the main app makes any changes to these, we would want the sister app to get those changes. Sorry if I wasnt clear

Comment: CCS and Javascript can be out of a shared location (CDN). You should be able to reference them from you new app directly off you old also. (You may have some XSS issues). Views are the hard part. Views are based on models, which are served by controllers. A view by itself is worthless. So to use a view, you would also have to use the same Viewmodel. Assuming you have already thought about this and its not an issue. you can store views in sql as they are effectively text! its ticker to debug them. I still think your approach to this will lead to tears. but they are your tears and not mine :).